# ANT->Maven task translator(or just use Maven Ant Tasks)

Tags: maven-2, ant, maven, maven-3, maven-ant-tasks

Is there a guide that outlines how to perform each of the following ant tasks using Maven?

http://ant.apache.org/manual/tasklist.html

Is it considered best practice to use Maven for these tasks or just run them in ANT via ant tasks feature.

Comment: If you give more precise information which kind of build/task you have to do someone can help with an appropriate answer how to achieve this in Maven.

Answer (score 3):

There is no mapping between ant tasks and "Maven tasks", because Maven doesn't have tasks. Its philosophy is completely different.

Ant is imperative: you tell Ant what to do with a sequence of parameterized tasks.

Maven is descriptive: you describe which kind of project you have, respect a set of conventions (or describe how you broke these conventions, and Maven decides which tasks it must do.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere there's a table that shows Maven plugins that are analagous to given Ant tasks, but I can't seem to find it. The ["Available Plugins"](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html) list might help you out.

Comment: I remember seeing this somewhere on maven site, but it was a bit misleading; plus, it showed replacing ~5-line ant xml for zip with ~20 lines of maven - it's better to learn the maven's declarative approach than trying to translate

Comment: @Petr: I agree that it's essential to learn how to do things in Maven, but for a beginner, it's nice to have a quick list of how common things are done in Maven. Also, I'm thinking of a different list. It doesn't show XML. It just shows common Ant tasks and the corresponding maven plugin to do the work, e.g. Ant's javac -> maven-compiler plugin, Ant's jar -> maven-jar plugin...

Comment: ok, perhaps the list of codehaus plugins will help you:
http://mojo.codehaus.org/plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of ant-task-to-maven-plugin at the end of this page -> http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html

Unfortunately, it only covers a small subset of ant tasks.

I've recently mavenized ant-based project (I really had it with dependency management) and from that experience I had very little need to retain Ant code.  The only place I've used antrun plugin was around custom code generation.

I think that it's perfectly fine to delegate some tasks to ant (and sometimes even to scripts) if that's well documented and saves time and maintenance cost.

One other place where I still use `antrun` is for echoing some environment properties and generic text to a build output, but maybe it's just my ignorance and there is a Maven way for that.

Comment: That's the one I was looking for :)